# Elasticsearch query - AND doesnt return values (when I know it should)

Tags: search, elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

I try to get data from elasticsearch with the exact filtering that I have on a Kibana3 dashboard, and for some reason can't make it make sense.

this is what I have on Kibana (which returns docs):
[image: kibana filters]

and this is a query that I try to run against ES and get no results:

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter": {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                    { "term" : { "domain_name.raw": "foo.bar" } },
                    { "term" : { "method": "get" } }
                ],
                "should" : {
                    "or" : [
                            {
                                "term" : { "pathname.raw" : "/xxxxx" }
                            },
                            {
                                "term" : { "pathname.raw" : "/yyyyy" }
                            },
                            {
                                "term" : { "pathname.raw" : "/zzzzz" }
                            }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I've been cracking my head on it for a few hours and can't get it to work.
when I remove one of the must terms (either the domain_name or the method), I do get results. but then I'ts not exactly the filtering I need...
any idea where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your syntax is a bit off, when using `should` you don't need to use `or`, try this:

I try to get data from elasticsearch with the exact filtering that I have on a Kibana3 dashboard, and for some reason can't make it make sense.

this is what I have on Kibana (which returns docs): kibana filters

and this is a query that I try to run against ES and get no results:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
            "term": {
              "domain_name.raw": "foo.bar"
            }
          }, {
            "term": {
              "method": "get"
            }
          }],
          "should": [{
              "term": {
                "pathname.raw": "/xxxxx"
              }
            }, {
              "term": {
                "pathname.raw": "/yyyyy"
              }
            }, {
              "term": {
                "pathname.raw": "/zzzzz"
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```